# Check if KFunction<*> is an extension function/instance function/object function/top level function?

Tags: kotlin, reflection

How I can check if KFunction is one of mentioned function types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can piece together this information with [`extensionReceiverParameter`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/extension-receiver-parameter.html) and [`instanceParameter`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/instance-parameter.html).  If it has an `extensionReceiverParameter`, it's an extension function.  If it doesn't have an `instanceParameter`, it's a top-level function.  Then you can take the type of the `instanceParameter` and test to see if it is an object to determine if it is an instance function or an object function.

Comment: A KFunction without an `instanceParameter` could also be an anonymous function. For example, from inside a class, call `println(::toString.instanceParameter)` and the result is `null` because the KFunction is already bound to the class as the receiver.

Comment: I also found something to check declaring context to check if function is top-level, forgot to post it here.